# Copy/Replicate subsets of tables from different databases into third database

Tags: database, database-design, postgresql, replication, database-replication

I have two databases:
1) accounts-management 
2) games-management

I want to make reports, which use data from both databases and i want to have third database which is suitable for reporting.

So, how can i copy/replicate/use cron job/etc a subset of tables from 1) db and other subset of tables from 2) db into third db (the reporting db).

I user postgres 9

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions I see:

- (preferred) create just one database, but with three separate [schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-schemas.html)
- use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) to communicate between multiple databases within main connection

> There are several reasons why one
>   might want to use schemas:
>
> - To organize database objects into logical groups to make them more
>     manageable.

Comment: I'd go for the two schema solution. Makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Slony can do this.  Just make two replication sets, one from db1 to db3, and another from db2 to db3.  As long as the table names don't conflict you can have them all in the same schema and database no problem.

Comment: I don't want to copy/replicate all tables from the first and second database, but only a subset of tables.

Comment: Slony (or londiste) allows you to specify which tables from a database to replicate.

Comment: Please go read the docs for slony or londiste.  I know for a fact slony can do this as I've done it.  I'm pretty sure that as Gavin said londiste can do it as well, but I've never actually deployed londiste.